# JavaScript Interfaces, Imports - When? (I want to port something from AS3)

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3

). I was eagerly waiting for JavaScript 1.8.5 only to find out it brings very little to the table. ActionScript 3 is ECMAScript 5 compliant, but apparently Interfaces aren't?

When will JS have some decent OO support? I consider Interfaces to be very important for type safety.

I also have another question, regarding the ability to "import" folders/classes in a file, which is done in AS3 using the "import" statement. Now, I'm aware that this is all related to the AS3 compiler, but I got a rather large project (a game) which I want to port to HTML 5 using JS and I am worried about how my code will be organizable.

It's rather hard to include 50 classes in a web page (supposedly, the page where the HTML5 version of the game will be located), don't you think?

What would you do?

Comment: i'm having some trouble parsing what the actual question is here.

Comment: Tip: Read the title. Then, the text ::- ). Alternatively, install a newer Perl parser. Seriously now, I'm asking about opinion & knowledge concerning porting stuff from AS3 to JS.

Comment: what i meant is that you're asking multiple vagueish questions in one. i can't really see what interfaces have to do with the amount of classes you'd include on a page?

Comment: The question is "how to port" and I detailed it. It's not vague. I simply have more questions but they are all in the same package: JS & AS3 & EcmaScript: how to stich'em together. Should I make 5 separate questions? I edited. I hope it's clearer now. I believe my question doesn't deserve a "close" vote just because I want to discuss something of a larger scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the part about handling multiple javascript files. You could use a web resource optimizer like [wro4j](http://code.google.com/p/wro4j/).

Using it you would specify groups like this:

```
<group name="group1">
  <js>file1.js</js>
  <js>file2.js</js>
  <js>file3.js</js>
  <js>file4.js</js>
  <css>file1.css</css>
  <css>file2.css</css>
  <group-ref>some-other-group</group-ref>
</group>
```

And inside the html page you would import a group like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/wro/group1.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/wro/group1.js"></script>
```

Beside just grouping and joining multiple files like this it can also minify the code, gzip and handle caching.

Comment: Hey Dan ::- ). That's one of the things I was looking for, indeed. Multumesc mult ;;- ).

Comment: It's a great tool. We've been using it at work for a rather large project: ~25 js files for the commons group + 2-3 js/css per page. Actually we don't use the group-ref feature that much, Keeping the commons groups separate allows us to have just two requests per page (commons group which rarely changes, and a really small group having just the logic for the page). This way when the user visits one of our pages, the commons group is already cached, and the page group is really small and fast to download.